# removeAttribute results in undefined

Tags: javascript

This is my first few lines of Javascript ever written and stuck already.

```
    <div id=form_template2 style="border: 1px solid black"></div>

    <script>
        const form_template = document.getElementById('form_template2')
        console.log(form_template.removeAttribute("style"))
    </script>
```

As soon as I add the .removeAttribute('style') bit I just get undefined in the console.log :/

Comment: what do you expect ? `removeAttribute` has no return value

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute Return value: undefined

Comment: This is a proper juvenile question. I don't see a reason to downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some functions in JavaScript just don't return anything. And in JavaScript world, that nothing is `undefined`. When you define your own function as:

```js
function lazy() {
    // does nothing
}
```

And then you try `console.log(lazy())` on it, the result will be the same - `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, I totally misunderstood what the function does. I thought I could get an element, remove attributes from it and replace some text in it, then add it elsewhere in the DOM.

Comment: Nah bro, it just removes the attribute :)

Answer (score 1):

removeAttribute doesn't return a value, so you'll get undefined.
Check out the documentation of the function at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute